# AWS ellasticache with memcache python .set() returns 0

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, memcached

I am a new user to memcache and ellasticache. I am using python environment for development. I have successfully created the ellacsticache cluster in aws and also created a node, therfore got two DNS, one for cluster itself and another for the node. Now I am using memcache in python from one of my instances that belongs to the same security group as the ellasticache cluster.

```
>>> import memcache
>>> mc = memcache.Client(['client-facing-pi.6qkr6p.0001.apse1.cache.amazonaws.com:11211'], debug=0)
>>> mc.set('hello','world')
0
```

So, I am getting 0 as return.

I even tried with the cluster dns, but that is also returning 0 in case of setting a value. What is the problem?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to access it? From the webserver: `telnet client-facing-pi.6qkr6p.0001.apse1.cache.amazonaws.com 11211`.  If you get a black screen it's working. Try some [telnet commands](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewCommands).

Comment: Not able to connect via telnet. :( :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem As I was using VPS, I had to go to my instances, and then in the security group, I had to add cache clusters port number i.e. 11211. And now it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

ElastiCache uses what's known as a [Cache Security Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/CacheSecurityGroup.html) - note that it isn't the same as the regular security groups you've been dealing with so far.  You will need to enable access to this and allow your EC2 instance to access it.  You can read more on managine [Cache Security Groups here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/ManagingSecurityGroups.html).

Comment: I don't see this option in the navigation bar in the left side.

Comment: @user1532043 Are you in a vpc?

Comment: Yeah think so. There are security groups for my instances, an while creating the cache cluster I also selected the same security group.

Comment: I am in VPC, that I found out from cache subnet group. My VPC id is same as my security group VPC id.